# React Native install [Mac M1]

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, react-native, npm

I m installing React-native to my mac book m1

But i think, i installed all(npm, jdk, node, rosseta, cocoapad, vscode, android studio, xcode and so on...). But if i run command(npm start), there is no dir (ios, android and so on...)
'node_modules    package.json    yarn.lock'
how can I build react native example?
if run command (npm react-native run-ios)

```
error iOS project folder not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?.
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I tried delete and reinstall npm, node, react-native...

But it's not working. there is no directory like ios/ , android/

I don't know what should i do?

Comment: What command have you used to create your react native project?

Comment: I tried ''react-native start"

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to create react native project :

```
npx react-native init project-name
```

Comment: use the exact command as I have mentioned above

Comment: I already that command. But Error is occur like below.
```
Using yarn v1.22.19
...
yarn add v1.22.19
...
warning "react-native > @react-native-community/cli > @react-native-community/cli-
...
warning " > react-native@0.70.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@18.1.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
...
node:internal/readline/emitKeypressEvents:71
            throw err;
            ^
TypeError: cli.init is not a function
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:302:7)
 ...
```